# Recursion C image compressor algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to complete a simple basic program that mimics an algorithm that is used in image compression using recursion.
I have an n x n matrix where n is always a power of two.This is because we can split the matrix in 4 n/2 * n/2 other matrix.
There are two base cases :

- when a matrix is 1x1 just return the value inside that location.
- when all the values inside an n x n block are equal then print 1x, where x is the common value

The recursive case is when we have different values.In that case we print 0 and we divide the matrix in other four n/2 x n/2 matrix.

These regions are recursively processed in clock-wise order, staring with the upper-left region.

Example :

```
8
..**....
..**....
**......
**......
........
........
......*.
......*.
```

Answer : 001.1*1.1*1.01.1.0*..*1.1.

My problem is that I am missing a case in my code so my answer doesn't really  totally match with the expected result.

Here is my code :

```
void computeComressor(char** arr,int m,int x,int y){
    int i,j;
    int flag=1;
    char c=arr[x][y];
    if(m==1){
        printf("%c",c);
        return;
    }
    for(i=x;i<m-x*y;i++){
        for(j=y;j<m-x*y;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]==c){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(flag==1){
        printf("1%c",c);
    }
    else{
        printf("0");
        computeComressor(arr,m/2,x,y);
        computeComressor(arr,m/2,x,m/2);
        computeComressor(arr,m/2,m/2,m/2);
        computeComressor(arr,m/2,m/2,y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `computeCompressor()` arguments on recursion seems wrong. If you pass `m/2` for x or y argument, it will result to 4, 2 and 1 based on the recursion level which does not correspond to the top-left corner of the submatrices. You have to add `x` and `y` values of the current submatrix to `m/2`. But even in that case, your code walks the submatrix in counter clockwise order.

Here is the fix I propose for `computeCompressor()` with few extra modifications:

```
void computeComressor(char** arr, int m, int x, int y){
    int     i,j;
    char    c   = arr[x][y];
    int     hm  = m / 2;

    if (m==1) {
        printf("%c", c);
        return;
    }

    for (i=x; i<x+m; i++) {
        for (j=y; j<y+m; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != c) {
                printf("1%c", c);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("0");
    computeComressor(arr, hm, x + 0,    y + 0);
    computeComressor(arr, hm, x + hm,   y + 0);
    computeComressor(arr, hm, x + hm,   y + hm);
    computeComressor(arr, hm, x + 0,    y + hm);
}
```

Comment: Didn't really worked your way as every case gave me only 1. , but I've discovered where I was wrong actually from your description. The stopping condition m-x*y was my mistake (besides the fact that I was not adding m/2 when was using recursion but that I've solved before you indicated that in your answer).